# Odd requests from Mobile Safari in access.log

Tags: mobile-safari

In access.log of a web server a see the following 9 requests:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1 | /example_page.php
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
MobileSafari/602.1 CFNetwork/811.4.18 Darwin/16.5.0 | /apple-touch-icon.png
```

The same 9 requests from the same IP address that request the same URLs are repeated several times a day. There are no other requests from the same IP.

It seems like JavaScript is not executed on the **example_page.php** page during these requests. What does these requests mean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior for a Safari browser. The browser is looking for icons that might look better than the normal favicon in order to show your icon in various contexts (like in bookmark links, or on the default home screen showing frequently visited sites). See more information about this behavior here...

[Apple Developer - Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)